# How do I specify the lifetime on a generic type passed to function by move?

Tags: generics, rust, lifetime

I'd like to wrap a function in a struct to package it with other data. When I specify the input type of the function explicitly, it works fine. When I attempt to generalize the pattern into a generic struct, I run into lifetime errors.

I've shared a code snippet in a playground and below. As is this does not compile. If I switch from `Wrapper` to `WrapperExplicit`, it works perfectly. What's going wrong? How I can make this wrapper generic?

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=92cac14257aaec53b648df93566ac3df

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct Reference<'a, X> {
    x : & 'a mut X 
}

//Works
struct WrapperExplicit<F> 
    where F : Fn(Reference<String>)
{
    data : u64,
    func : F,
}
impl<F> WrapperExplicit<F>
    where F : Fn(Reference<String>)
{
    pub fn new(func: F) -> WrapperExplicit<F> {
        WrapperExplicit {
            data : 10,
            func: func,
        }
    }

    pub fn call(& mut self, arg: Reference<String>)
    {
        (self.func)(arg)
    }
}

//Doesn't work
struct Wrapper<F, U> 
    where F : Fn(U)
{
    data : u64,
    func : F,
    _marker: PhantomData<U>,
}

impl<F,U> Wrapper<F,U>
    where F : Fn(U)
{
    pub fn new(func: F) -> Wrapper<F,U> {
        Wrapper {
            data : 0,
            func: func,
            _marker: PhantomData {}
        }
    }

    pub fn call(& mut self, arg: U)
    {
        (self.func)(arg)
    }
}

fn fn_borrow(x : Reference<String>) {
    println!("{}", x.x);
}

fn fn_move(y : String) {
    println!("{}", &y);
}

pub fn test_example() {
    let mut f = Wrapper::new(fn_borrow); //Doesn't work
    // let mut f = WrapperExplicit::new(fn_borrow); //Works
    let mut y = "Hello!".to_string();
    let x = Reference{ x : &mut y};
    f.call(x);
    fn_move(y);
    println!("{}", f.data)
}
```

---

EDIT:
Here's an even simpler example:
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0f4f5236d4e4439b3bec5a717f62567c

I believe the issue is that because the generic type has to be set when you create the struct, the lifetime for the generic type is set then as well, so you can't use a different lifetime when you call the struct's associated function. Is that true? Is there a way to let the "type" part of the struct be generic, but leave the lifetime to be decided when one of the struct's functions is called?

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

//Doesn't work
struct WrapperSimple<U> 
{
    data : u64,
    _marker: PhantomData<U>,
}

impl<U> WrapperSimple<U>
{
    pub fn new() -> WrapperSimple<U> {
        WrapperSimple {
            data : 0,
            _marker: PhantomData {}
        }
    }

    pub fn call(& mut self, _arg: U)
    {
    }
    pub fn call2<V>(& mut self, _arg: V)
    {
    }
}

fn fn_move(y : String) {
    println!("{}", &y);
}

fn main() {
    let mut w = WrapperSimple::<&str>::new();
    let mut y = "Hello!".to_string();
    let x = & mut y;
    w.call(x); //Doesn't work
    //w.call2(x); //Works, (obviously)
    fn_move(y);
    println!("{}", w.data)
}
```

---

EDIT 2:

I think here's how it ultimately shakes out:

- You can't store a generic function with generic inputs in a struct
  without referencing the function's input type in the struct's type
  parameters, and therefore also need a PhantomData field of that type
  (otherwise you have an unconstrained or unused type parameter)
- Once you have a field of that type, the type's embedded lifetime has
  to be set when the struct is monomorphized, for example at
  construction
- That means the lifetime is fixed and cannot vary each
  time you call one of the struct's methods
- You also can't create a new generic type parameter for the method and constrain it to match the struct's type parameter, except stripping the struct type's lifetime

Therefore, what I want to accomplish is not currently supported by rust's type system. Please let me know if one of my assumptions here is wrong.

Comment: This looks like higher-kinded types are needed to express this properly, which are not supported by Rust yet. There are often work-arounds, but I can't think of an easy one in this case.

Comment: If you can somehow change the argument type of `call` to `&mut U` instead of `U`, this would work fine. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=edf9d7a37e9b587b4045ef56a0818e48

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, Sven. I think higher-kinded types would be one approach, but you could also get it to work if there were a way to bound generic types with other types rather than traits. In other words something like
`pub fn call<'a,'b,V>(& 'a mut self, _arg: V)
where V : U + 'b
    {
    }
`
Where `U + 'b` means the same type as `U`, but with the lifetime `'b` for the type rather than whatever lifetime was originally bound to U.

Comment: Unfortunately your example only works because U doesn't have any embedded references, and so no associated lifetime, the way you call it. If you replace `str` with `&str`, then it again doesn't work.

Comment: The `U + 'b` syntax would be ambiguous, since `U` could be parametrised by any number of lifetime parameters at different nesting levels, and it would be unclear what lifetime the `'b` constrains. Moreover, the lifetime bound `'b` on a generic type means that the type lives _at least_ for this lifetime. You need to _reduce_ the lifetime here to resolve the conflict, so this wouldn't be a solution regardless.

Comment: Yeah, good points. I guess the idea is you want to strip away all of the lifetime bounds implied by U, but maybe this ends up being too much of a special case to have a language feature for it. Anyway, sounds like rust doesn't support it